# How do I insert records into my custom WordPress table?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am generally more familiar with creating INSERT statements into SQL or Oracle databases.

However, I created a custom database called CustomerDB and custom table in WordPress using phpMyAdmin.

I am attempting to use the following code to insert a record into the custom table.

I am not getting any errors but no record is getting inserted.

Please note that at this point, I am not concerned about sql injection attack.

I will deal with that once my INSERT code is working.

Does anyone know why the following code is not inserting records into the table in WordPress?

```
<?php
//make database accessible
global $wpdb;
// Get data
$customername = $_POST["customername"];
$custaddress = $_POST["custaddress"];
$custcity = $_POST["custcity"];
$custstate = $_POST["custstate"];
$custzip = $_POST["custzip"];


// Database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","myuser","mypass","CustomerDB");
if(!$conn) {
die('Problem in database connection: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Data insertion into database
$query = "INSERT INTO ‘CustomerDB.wp_customTable’ ( ‘customername’, ‘custaddress’, ‘custcity’, ‘custstate’,‘custzip’ ) VALUES ( $customername, $custaddress, $custcity, $custstate,custzip )";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);

// Redirection to the success page
header("Location: thankyou.php");
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you missed the dollar `$` off custzip.

Comment: ... also, invalid usage of mysql_error, wrong quotes around identifiers, database name and table name need to be quoted separately, string literals in SQL need to be enclosed in single quotes, no test for unsuccessful execution and no retrieval of error message, potentially unsafe values included in SQL text,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step, modify the code to check to check for successful query execution. If the execution returns FALSE, then retrieve the error.

As an example:

```
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   printf('Error: %s',mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

The message retrieved by the `mysqli_error` function should give us some indication of what the problem is.

The failure shouldn't be mysterious. We should anticipate that something could go wrong. If our code doesn't do that, it's putting it's pinky finger to the corner of it's mouth with a Dr.Evil-style "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?"

Adding that small modification would go a long ways towards answering the question that was asked: **"Why the following code is not inserting ...?**"

---

To the question, **"How do I insert [rows]..."**

We note there are several problems in the SQL text.

First, ditch the ‘smartquotes’. To escape identifiers, enclose them in backtick characters. Each identifier must be enclosed separately. If `CustomerDB` is the database name and `wp_customTable` is the table name, then this is wrong:

```
‘CustomerDB.wp_customTable’
^                         ^
```

If we are going to quote the identifiers, then we quote each of the identifiers separately, like this:

```
`CustomerDB`.`wp_customTable`
^          ^ ^              ^
```

Note that those identifiers are valid, and don't actually require backticks. In this case, we could omit the backticks. We'll leave them as a demonstration.

--

Defense Number 1 against SQL Injection is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders. Do not include any potentially unsafe values in the SQL text.

Example:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `CustomerDB`.`wp_customTable` ( `customername`'
     . ', `custaddress`, `custcity`, `custstate`, `custzip` )'
     . ' VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )';

if( $sth = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql) ) {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'sssss'
      ,$customername
      ,$custaddress
      ,$custcity
      ,$custstate
      ,$custzip
   );
   if( mysqli_stmt_execute($sth) ) {
      // statement execution successful
   } else {
      printf("Error: %s\n",mysqli_stmt_error($sth));
   }
} else {
   printf("Error: %s\n",mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

If there's some reason we can't use prepared statements with bind placeholders, then any potentially unsafe value that is being included in the SQL text *must* be properly escaped, using the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function.

--

Also, if the `mysqli_connect` fails, use the `mysqli_connect_error` function to retrieve the error message, not `mysql_error`.

Comment: and GurV, thank you two very much for your kindness.

I am getting some error that  am trying to work out now. I think I can resolve those but just in case, here it is:

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\Customers\scripts\final.php on line 38
 Error: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Comment: The first error is weird because I am using same code and same number of fields.

Comment: The 2nd argument to msyqli_bind_param is the "type definition string". That should be a literal string containing *five* 's' characters (assuming that the values are being passed as strings.)  The 3rd through 7th arguments are the *five* values to be supplied. And there are *five* bind placeholders (question mark characters) in the SQL text. I'm looking at the code in my answer, and I'm not seeing it problem. It looks right to me. If you modified this code, be sure you that there are *seven* arguments to mysqli_stmt_bind_param, starting with the statement handle, followed by the type string

Comment: Typical oversight error. I corrected that very quickly as soon as I posted the comments. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Tairoc: I wish you success in your endeavor. I hope that you found this answer helpful. On a parting note: Security is *not* an afterthought to be applied after code is written. My recommendation is to adopt coding patterns that are secure from the get go. Do that *before* insecure coding becomes a familiar habit, and *before* there's a mountain of working code that will need to be fixed and re-tested. I recommend the OWASP project. In this day and age, we should not be producing code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection or XSS   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: total agree and point well taken.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks instead of quotes:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO CustomerDB.`wp_customTable`(`customername`, `custaddress`, `custcity`, `custstate`,`custzip` ) VALUES ( $customername, $custaddress, $custcity, $custstate, custzip )";
```